# convert all T/F values from userform to numbers when populating cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am nearing completion of my first userform to data table template many thanks to you all!

I'm puzzled however as to how I am going to pivot all this data that populates onto my sheet from the userform selections as they return "True" & "False" values.

My only thought in order to get the averages/totals I need, is to have the values change to 1 & 0 respectively. Is there a way to code all true or false values of checkboxes to these numbers before populating the data on the sheet or will I have to manually change the value of each box so that it places a 1 or 0 in the destined cell? As you could imagine.

ex.
`"desired cell range".Value = checkbox1.Value`

Picture example of what populates the data table, which is 35 rows across.
[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding some more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkbox1.Value` returns a `Boolean`.  If you want to cast it to a number, just use `CInt()` (or `CLng()`).  VBA treats `0` as `False` and `-1` as `True`, so if you want your averages/totals to be positive, take the absolute value:

```
{desired cell range}.Value = Abs(CInt(checkbox1.Value))
```

Comment: thanks so much for the reply. There is no way to code it to entail every value though? I have 35 different criteria generating data, most of which are checkboxes.

If I have to rewrite each so be it, was just hoping I could stick something at the beginning and/or end of the button click or userform.

Comment: @Awill - Not unless you're using something like an array of controls. You could update all of the cells *again* afterward, but that would be horribly inefficient.  Just copy and paste the code into an editor that does regex search and replace - should be a quick job if you don't want to hunt everything down.